# why is my view in fragment shuffling when I am inflating a layout according to onConfigurationChanged?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I am trying to inflate a fragment dynamically based on the orientation in on config changed. I am not letting the activity to destroy itself. And I am using three layouts two in normal layout directory and one in layout-land directory. The issue is that whenever I change the orientation dynamically, the layouts are shuffling although both the layouts are displaying properly on initial loading of the fragment.  here is my code:

SplashFragment.java

```
package com.vipulsoftwares.ssapunjab;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Toast;

import static com.vipulsoftwares.ssapunjab.R.id.toolbar;

/**
 * Created by vipul on 10/26/2016.
 */

public class SplashFragment extends Fragment {
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
    ViewGroup contain;
    View v;
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        layoutInflater=inflater;
        contain=container;
        v= inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_splash,container,false);
        return v;

    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                FragmentTransaction ft=getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                Fragment fragment = new InstructionsFragment();
                Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
                bundle.putString("uploader","SSA");
                fragment.setArguments(bundle);
                ft.replace(R.id.frame, fragment, fragment.getClass().getName());
                getActivity().setTitle("SSA");
                ft.commit();

            }
        },3000);
    }


    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        getView().setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
        getView().requestFocus();

        getView().setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
                if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
                        //Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Back Pressed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        return true;
                    }
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
    }
    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        if(newConfig.orientation==Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE)
        {

            layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_splash_land, contain, false);
        }
        else
        {

            layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_splash, contain, false);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: try getting orientation from activity and send this to fragment via some callback. Fragment's onConfigurationchanges is not trustworthy

Comment: I have found out that my dynamic layout inflator from onConfigurationChanged in fragment is not actually changing the layout. Is there a method from which I can change the layout dynamically in the fragment itself if I dont want to intricate matters by using callbacks between activity and fragment

Answer (score 0):

This is the way to change the fragment layout dynamically from OnConfigChanged:

```
 @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        contain.removeAllViews();
        if(newConfig.orientation==Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE)
        {

            layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_splash_land, contain);
        }
        else
        {
            layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_splash, contain);
        }
    }
```